# How do I move JAR from WEB-INF\lib folder to another folder in WAR file using Gradle?

Tags: gradle, jar, war

I want to move a JAR from WEB-INF\lib folder to another folder in the WAR file.
The following does not work:

```
war { 
        // I don't want my.jar in WEB-INF\lib folder 
        exclude "**/my.jar"

        // I want my.jar in "myFolder" folder 
        into("myFolder") {
            def myFiles = classpath.filter{ File file -> file.name.endsWith("my.jar")}

            from(myFiles)
        }
}
```

The my.jar is not in "myFolder" folder.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your `exclude` statement will exclude any file following the pattern `**/my.jar` from being processed by the task, even in the subspec. But you don't want to exclude the file, you just want to modify its path:

```
war {
    filesMatching('**/my.jar') { file ->
        file.path = 'myFolder/' + file.name
    }
}
```

Comment: Does not work: my.jar is still in WEB-INF\lib folder.

Comment: Sorry, I did not know that `path` should be the full path, so I added the file name. If it still does not work, could you add something like `eachFile { file -> println file.path }` to your build script and paste the output into your question?

Comment: WEB-INF\lib is not in the output.

Comment: myFolder/my.jar is in the output.